# using ClaimsIdentity ext. method from controller

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I've found this extension method which returns roles of logged user.

```
public static List<string> Roles(this ClaimsIdentity identity)
    {
        return identity.Claims
                       .Where(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Role)
                       .Select(c => c.Value)
                       .ToList();
    }
```

how can I use this ext. method from controller? or is it possible to extend further this method in order to use User.Identity and then get users roles?

Answer (score 0):

```
namespace Identity.Extensions
{
    public static class UserExtensions()
    {
        public static List<string> Roles(this ClaimsIdentity identity)
        {
        return identity.Claims
                   .Where(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Role)
                   .Select(c => c.Value)
                   .ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

Get the namespace that the extension method sits in, the example above would be `Identity.Extensions` and add it as a using statement to the file where you want to use the method.

```
using Identity.Extensions;
```

Then when you have a `ClaimsIdentity` object, such as the one returned from your User Manager's `CreateIdentityAsync` method, you will be able to access this method:

```
using Identity.Extensions;

public class YourClass()
{
    public void DoSoemthingWithUser()
    {
         var identity = await this.UserManager.CreateIdentityAsync(user, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

        // Use extension method
        var roles = identity.Roles();
    }

    public UserManager UserManager
    {
        get
        {
            return HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<UserManager<IdentityUser>>(); 
        }
    }
}
```